# Angular Controller Arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a angular code from this page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

```
1 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
2 
3 myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
4     $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
5 }]);
```

On line #3 above, what is the purpose of the string `'$scope'`?

Can't I just do this?
`myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', function($scope) { ... })`

What is the benefit of having an array and the name of the argument there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely write it `myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', function($scope) { ... })`
.

Both ways are right.

The difference is that you are inline annotating the function, so that when you minify your script your dependencies work fine.

When you write $scope as an argument to the function, the angular compiler injects the scope variable in your controller. And it has to be only the $cope nothing else.

So when you minify your script the name of variables get changed. So in normal case your script wont work if you change the name variables. So you write the actual name of variables in the array notation( This the way to annotate in angularJS).

Check Angular JS official document:[Angular JS Dependency Injection[1](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: There is a pretty neat https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin that allows you to write the less-verbose version, which is then filled in with the minification-safe version during a build process.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the argument is to make sure that the angular dependency injector can identify the object to inject if the code is minified.

See [A Note on Minification](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) section on the angular site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted a different answer because it contained a bit more information. Thanks!

Comment: I thought the internet was getting full so didn't want to duplicate what was already on the angular site on here ;)